# blackberry maps do not show correct location on the device

Tags: blackberry, maps

well frnds my code for maps works well and shows all pics and gradient paths very well on the simulator after simulating the gps ,but it does not works on the device....

The gps on device is working properly as google maps and other work related to gps are working perfectly fine

my code

```
         if(GPS_Location.lati!=0.0 && GPS_Location.longi!=0.0)
            {                       
                User_latitude = ((GPS_Location.lati)*100000);
                User_longitude = ((GPS_Location.longi)*100000);

                User_La = String.valueOf(User_latitude).substring(0, String.valueOf(User_latitude).lastIndexOf('.'));
                User_Lo = String.valueOf(User_longitude).substring(0, String.valueOf(User_longitude).lastIndexOf('.'));

             if(param.equals("")) //for find business near me
             {

                 document1 = "<location-document>" +
                                "<location lon='"+User_Lo+"' lat='"+User_La+"' label='User' />"+
                                "<location lon='"+User_Lo+"' lat='"+User_La+"' label='"+"User"+"' />"+
                             "</location-document>";
             }
             if(!param.equals("")) //for the directions
             {
                 Business_latitude = Double.parseDouble(param.substring(0, param.lastIndexOf(',')));
                 Business_longitude = Double.parseDouble(param.substring(param.lastIndexOf(',')+1,param.length())); 

                 Business_latitude = Business_latitude*100000;                   
                 Business_longitude = Business_longitude*100000;

                 Business_La = String.valueOf(Business_latitude).substring(0, String.valueOf(Business_latitude).lastIndexOf('.'));                  
                 Business_Lo = String.valueOf(Business_longitude).substring(0, String.valueOf(Business_longitude).lastIndexOf('.'));

                 document1 = "<location-document>" +
                                "<GetRoute>"+
                            "<location lon='"+User_Lo+"' lat='"+User_La+"' label='User' />"+
                            "<location lon='"+Business_Lo+"' lat='"+Business_La+"' label='"+"User"+"' />"+
                            "</GetRoute>"+
                        "</location-document>";
             }
              Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS,new MapsArguments(MapsArguments.ARG_LOCATION_DOCUMENT,document1));
         }
```

this code works on simulator but not fine on device.
just points a pin indicating user and nothing else

what to do????

Comment: what device/os version? have you signed you app? are you sure the last build is deployed to device? have you tried to debug? maybe aram.equals("") is always true by some reason?

Comment: simulator on which i tried-8330 curve,
device on which i deployed-9000 bold,
cod file is signed with version 4.6,
what is aram.equals("")???????????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 document1 = 

"<lbs>
<location lon='"+User_Lo+"' lat='"+User_La+"' label='User, ON'    description='User' zoom='10'/>
</lbs>";
```

i tried this and it worked,also i worked around my gps value and it worked!!!!!!!!!!!!